# Default value on jQuery autocomplete with dropdown shown?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

Just wondering if someone can help...

I have implemented a jquery autocomplete function which works when a user types a search in an input box. But what I would really like to try and do is run this autocomplete on the page load with a predefined search variable.

So, if I have a search box on another page and the user enters for example 'ABC', I want to use this string as a search variable to then open up my page with the autocomplete widget, which on page load will enter this into my input text box and show the results straight away in the drop down.

Is something like this possible? How would I go about it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `search` method on jQuery autocomplete: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-search

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete( "search", "yourValueFromPreviousPage" );
```